# convert array of object to array of string - lodash

Tags: lodash

if i have the following array :

```
[
  {
    0:{
       id:5,
       name:'xxx'
      }
  },
  {
    1:{
       id:6,
       name:'yyy'
      }
  }
]
```

and i need to convert it to

```
['xxx', 'yyy']
```

how to implement that with Lodash ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a solution that makes use of lodash's [**flatMapDeep**](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#flatMapDeep) to extract the values before plucking the name:

```
let data = [
  {
    0:{
       id:5,
       name:'xxx'
      }
  },
  {
    1:{
       id:6,
       name:'yyy'
      }
  }
]

let result = _(data)
    .flatMapDeep(_.values)
    .map('name')
    .value()
```

**Edit**
Change the map to return a different value for each item. e.g to return the id and name as a key value pair you could do this:

```
let result = _(data)
    .flatMapDeep(_.values)
    .map( item => ({[item.id]: item.name}) )
    .value()
```

Comment: working now, thanks, what if i nedd to get the new array but with key - value combination ? like [{5,'xxx'}, {6,'yyy'}] ? how to implement that ?

Comment: Have added a snippet showing different values being returned for each item.

Answer (score 3):

You can use Lodash's [`map`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#map) method.

```js
var data = [
  {
    0:{
       id:5,
       name:'xxx'
      }
  },
  {
    1:{
       id:6,
       name:'yyy'
      }
  }
];

var arr = _.map(data, function(element, idx) {
  return element[idx].name;
});

console.log(arr);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.js"></script>
```

As yBrodsky pointed out, this assumes the object key continues to increase by one each time.

Answer (score 1):

No Lodash, but maybe:

```
var arr = [];

x.forEach(function(item, index) {
    arr.push(item[index].name)
});
console.log(arr)
```

This assuming the object key keeps increasing, 0, 1, 2....n

Answer (score 0):

How to: `_.map(data, "name").toString()`

#### JavaScript (example):

```js
var data = [
  {
    0:{
       id:5,
       name:'xxx'
      }
  },
  {
    1:{
       id:6,
       name:'yyy'
      }
  }
];

console.log(_.map(data, "name").toString());
```

#### Output:

```
xxx,yyy
```

## Human readable

```js
_.map(data, "name").join(', ')
// xxx, yyy
```